# What's so special about 'return' keyword

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

When I seemed to understand what return is for in Haskell, I tried to play with different alternatives and it seems that return not only can be used anywhere in the monad chain, but also can be excluded completely

```
*Main> Just 9 >>= \y -> (Just y) >>= \x -> return x
Just 9

*Main> Just 9 >>= \y -> (return y) >>= \x -> (Just y)
Just 9

*Main> Just 9 >>= \y -> (Just y) >>= \x -> (Just x)
Just 9
```

Even if I omit return in my own instancing, I only get warning...

```
data MaybeG a = NothingG | JustG a deriving Show 
instance Monad MaybeG where  
    --    return x = JustG x  
        NothingG >>= f = NothingG  
        JustG x >>= f  = f x  
        fail _ = NothingG  

Monad.hs:3:10:
    Warning: No explicit method nor default method for `return'
    In the instance declaration for `Monad MaybeG'
```

and I still can use the monad

```
*Main> JustG 9 >>= \y -> (JustG 11) >>= \x -> (JustG y)
JustG 9

*Main> JustG 9 >>= \y -> (NothingG) >>= \x -> (JustG y)
NothingG
```

So what's so special about the return keyword? Is this about more complex cases where I can not omit it? Or because this is the "right" way to do things even if they can be done differently?

**UPDATE:** 
.. or another alternative, I could define my own monadic value constructor

```
finallyMyLastStepG :: Int -> MaybeG Int
finallyMyLastStepG a = JustG a
```

and produce another variant of the same chain (with the same result)

```
*Main> JustG 9 >>= \y -> (JustG 11) >>= \x -> (finallyMyLastStepG y)
JustG 9
```

Comment: `return` is not a keyword. And yes, it doesn't do control flow like the keyword of the same name does in most imperative programming languages, so the `return ...` in `do { foo; return ...; quux }` is redundant.

Comment: @delnan, the problem is when I read everything about monads, 'return' at the last line looked like the requirement. But in my 3rd line I replaced it with direct monadic value creation and the Haskell is ok with this.

Comment: @Maksee: Having a return at the last line is not a requirement. It just so happens that for the Maybe monad, the bind operation contains a construction of a new simple monad. That's typically not the case; consider, say, the identity monad. It doesn't call `return` on anything in `bind`.

Answer (score 38):

> So what's so special about the return keyword?

Firstly, `return` is *not* a keyword in Haskell. It is an overloaded function.

Its type is given by:

```
class  Monad m  where
    -- | Sequentially compose two actions, passing any value produced
    -- by the first as an argument to the second.
    (>>=)       :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    -- | Inject a value into the monadic type.
    return      :: a -> m a
```

So you see that `return` is a function that given a value of type `a`, returns a new value of type `m a`, where `m` is some type that is an instance of `Monad`. Such types include:

- Monad `[]`
- Monad `I0`
- Monad `Maybe`
- Monad `STM`
- Monad `((->) r)`
- Monad `(Either e)`
- Monad `(ST s)`

and many more besides. Instances of 'Monad' should satisfy the following laws:

```
> return a >>= k  ==  k a
> m >>= return  ==  m
> m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  ==  (m >>= k) >>= h
```

The implementation of a function `a -> m a` is pretty easy to guess. Here's the definition for the most common monads:

*Lists*:

```
 return x = [x]
```

*Maybe*

```
 return x = Just x
```

So you see that the `return` is an overloaded function that "lifts" a value into a monadic wrapper. You can thus use it anywhere you can use its definition. E.g.

```
Prelude> 1 : return 2
[1,2]
```

or in [the `do` notion](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.bind) (useful when [chaining expressions](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#id638573)).

```
> do v <- return 7 ; return v :: Maybe Int
Just 7
```

The real reason to use a monadic `return` is when composing multiple values in some monad:

```
Prelude> do x <- return 1 ; y <- return 2 ; return (x + y) :: Maybe Int
Just 3
Prelude> do x <- Nothing  ; y <- return 2 ; return y
Nothing
```

In the last statement you see how the chain short-circuited once it hit a zero value for the given monad. In this case `Nothing`.

Summary: `return` is an overloaded function that lifts a value into a monadic wrapper. You use it when you need to lift values. It is *not* a control-flow keyword, as it is in imperative languages.

Comment: Ok, I see that applying "keyword" to "return" is wrong, but mostly my question was about whether should I always use it or I can safely use the other way of doing the same. In other words seeing that the same result can be returned several other ways, why should I follow the convention?

Comment: So, I can replace your last example with  _do x <- (Just 1); y <-(Just 2);(Just (x+y))_ and get the same result without using "return"

Comment: @Maksee: Yup, it does the same thing.

Comment: @Maksee It does the same thing, but it has one important shortcoming: It only works for `Maybe`s. If you use return you can use the same code for any monad (try [], for example).

Comment: @MikeHartl, great, the same code as in "copy-paste" working differently being pasted in different context or the same code as in function body being different by the polymorphic nature? It is better to be latter :)

Comment: @Maksee The same code as in defining a polymorphic function which works for arbitrary monads. This is critical for Haskell's libraries. One couldn't define functions like `mapM` or `sequence`, which work for arbitrary monads, without `return` - you could only ever define them for a single monad. Without this generality, there would be no point in monads, though!

Answer (score 13):

I suspect that you're misunderstanding what "return" means in the context of a monad in Haskell. return is a *function* that takes in an `a` and returns a "wrapped `a`" -- that is, the simplest possible instance of the monad. In other languages it is often called `Unit`.  It's not the "control flow" `return` that you see in C-like languages.

So in your example of the `Maybe` monad, we have return defined as a function that takes in an `a` and returns a `Maybe a`:

```
return :: a -> Maybe a
```

And what does it do? if you give it `x`, it gives you back `Just x`:

```
return x = Just x
```

And now you can use `return` as a shorthand when you need that function, rather than writing out:

```
\x -> Just x
```

It's called `return` because when you're writing out monads in `do` notation, it looks like what you'd do in a C-like language.

Comment: Ok, \x -> (Just x) in my third line does exactly the same, it returns the monadic value

Comment: Is it called `Unit`? AFAIK `Unit` as an alternative name for the empty tuple (or more abstractly/generally/correctly, the type with only one value).

Comment: @Eric_Lippert, so the 'return' is a syntax sugar? Seems like nobody ever mentions this.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, "unit" is often used for those purposes as well.

Comment: @Maksee: `return` is a requirement of the monad pattern. I'm running a series on gentle introduction to monads for object-oriented programmers on my blog right now; on it, I'm saying `CreateSimpleM` instead of `return` to keep it clear. You might want to check it out. http://ericlippert.com/category/monads, start from the bottom.

Comment: `return` is not syntax sugar. It is a function. Albeit a polymorphic one.

Comment: Technically, `Just` alone is also a suitable replacement for `(\x-> Just x)` since `Just` is an ordinary function..  Also, it's awesome to see Eric Lippert answering a Haskell question.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Hartl comment led me to the right direction, although was not so formal imho, so I just post my final understanding what so special about 'return' operator.

Any type class lists operator it supports and there are functions that can work only in this class context (imposed via class constratint symbol =>). So, for example filterM signature

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

shows us that it can be used only in monadic context. The magic is that in the body this function is free to use any operator the class has (>>= and return for Monad) and if an instance (for example my MaybeG ) lacks a method (return in my case) then the function can fail. So when the return is there

```
> filterM (\x -> JustG (x > 0)) [2, 1, 0, -1] 
JustG [2,1]
```

and when it's commented (see my implementation of MaybeG in the question)

```
> filterM (\x -> JustG (x > 0)) [2, 1, 0, -1] 

*** Exception: Monad.hs:3:10-21: No instance nor default method for class operation GHC.Base.return
```

so imlementation of any operator (return in monad case) is required if one plans to use the instance with functions working with this class (monad in this case) constraint.

I think my initial misunderstanding was due to the fact that most tutorials explains monadic chains without polymorphic (ad hoc) context. This context in my opinion makes monads more powerful and reusable.

Comment: Even when you know the `Monad` instance you are using, you may not know how it is implemented, so you have to use `return` to lift a value.  For instance, how would you lift a value into `IO` without `return`?