# How to do multiple actions in this Haskell list function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am coming from Python and it is quite hard for me to learn Haskell. For example I got this function which will merge lists. So the first thing is merging the lists then I want to return the sum of the merged list. How is the correct syntax?

```
merge:: [[a]] -> [a]
merge xss = foldr (++) [] xss
            return sum []
```

This piece of code will only work if I remove the last line. But I want to return the sum of the merged lists.

Comment: You can build this up from two separate functions: the first one actually does the merge, and the second one takes the sum. However, combining these (by "composition") should be done in a functional way: `f(g(x))` as math functions, or `f g x` in Haskell. Note, also, that the type of the sum is not `[a]`, but `a`, and also that `return` does not mean what you think it means in Haskell.

Comment: also, `return` is not what you it is in Haskell.

Comment: [`return`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323927/whats-so-special-about-return-keyword) doesn't mean what you think it does

Answer (score 6):

right now the only thing you get is a compile time error, complaining about multiple errors in your code - I guess the best thing would be to read a bit about haskell syntax (e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com)

```
merge :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

You have to add a typeclass constraint, so you can add the elements of a list - right now you say your function works on all possible elements you can and cannot think of.

```
merge:: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
```

to sum after the "merging" you have to declare an intermediate variable if you want to write it like you started.

```
merge xss = let tmp = foldr (++) [] xss
            in sum tmp
```

or you can write it a bit shorter

```
merge xs = sum $ concat xs
```

or pointfree if you want to even shorter

```
merge = sum . concat
```

Comment: also, `sum . map sum`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `foldr` with some arguments, and then call `sum` with the result of `foldr`.

You can do that easily by writing:

```
merge xss = sum (foldr (++) [] xss)
```

You do not need to write multiple "statements".

Comment: (I'm aware there is an existing answer with many suggestions; however, none of those directly show the asker how to write the code s/he appeared to be trying to write, without any other changes)